# Use "org.apache.commons.commons-io_2.11.0.jar" or "org.apache.commons.io_2.8.0.v20210415-0900.jar"?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, p2

**Step 1**

I download **eclipse-platform-4.26-win32-x86_64.zip** [here](https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.26-202211231800/) .

It uses `org.apache.commons.commons-io,2.11.0` in `bundles.info`.

**Step 2**

Then I install the feature **Eclipse PDE Plug-in Developer Resources 3.14.1400.v20221123-1800** through the p2 site https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2022-12 .

It uses `org.apache.commons.io,2.8.0.v20210415-0900` in `bundles.info`.

It follows that `org.apache.commons.commons-io,2.11.0` can not satisfy the installation of **Eclipse PDE Plug-in Developer Resources**, p2 chooses the lower version.

[image]

[image]

**Step 3**

Then I install the feature **Git integration for Eclipse - Source Code 6.4.0.202211300538-r** through the same p2 site.

It uses `org.apache.commons.commons-io,2.11.0` in `bundles.info`.

Emmm, `org.apache.commons.commons-io,2.11.0` can satisfy the feature **Eclipse PDE Plug-in Developer Resources** now ? ? ?

If **2.8.0** and **2.11.0** can both satisfy the feature **Eclipse PDE Plug-in Developer Resources**, why would p2 download a remote version **2.8.0** when **2.11.0** already exists locally in Step 2 ?

[image]

[image]

**Step 4**

I uninstall the feature **Git integration for Eclipse - Source Code**.(not revert)

The result is using `org.apache.commons.commons-io,2.11.0` in `bundles.info`.

This result is more crazy. The same features with different plug-ins ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: `org.apache.commons.commons-io` and `org.apache.commons.io` are different plug-in ids so they are regarded as completely separate plug-ins even if they happen to contain different versions of the same code.

Comment: All right, they are different plug-ins. But as far as the result of step 2 and 4，features are identical, but plug-ins are different. It's so confusing.